# How to update cell references when setting the Formula property in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, worksheet-function

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 For i = 1 To k        
    If Range("D2").Offset(i, 0).Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
   Else
      Range("D2").Offset(i, 0).Formula = Range("D2").Formula
```

The formula in D2 is

```
   =IF(F2<0,6;5;IF(F2<0,9;10;22))
```

The problem is that all cells in D column get the same formula. How can I change it so it auto-adjusts like in the Excel UI (eg F2 becomes F3 and so on)

Answer (score 1):

The formula property takes the formula exactly as specified. It doesn't know anything about adjusting the references. You would need to us string manipulation to fix up the copied formula before setting it in the new cell.

Perhaps it would be better to just build the formula in code rather than copying it and trying to fix it up.

Answer (score 1):

If perhaps there is a specific reason to use the autofill functionality of Excel (perhaps you don't know what the formula will be and want to keep your code simple) you can use the `Filldown` function.

You need to ensure, however, that the calculation mode (`CalcMode`) is set to automatic (`xlCalculationAutomatic`).

```
Range(Range("D2").Address & ":" & Range("D2").Offset(k, 0).Address).FillDown
```

Note: The above code should be taken out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served by breaking out the IF function from the cell and encode it within VBA.

If I've understood your IF function correctly (I gather you're not using an English version going by the punctuation model) it looks something like this in VBA:

```
If Range("D2").Offset(i, 2) < 0.6 Then
    Range("D2").Offset(i, 0) = 5
    ElseIf Range("D2").Offset(i, 2) < 0.9 Then
        Range("D2").Offset(i, 0) = 10
        Else
            Range("D2").Offset(i, 0) = 22
End If
```

This would replace this line in your code:

```
Range("D2").Offset(i, 0).Formula = Range("D2").Formula
```

I'm using offset(i,2) to refer to the queried column in F2.